# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Guid' to type 'System.IConvertible'

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

I'm trying to use the WCF-SQL adaptor in BizTalk 2013 to return records from a stored procedure.
I followed a simple [online walkthrough](http://www.enterpriseapplicationsdevelopment.com/2010/02/how-to-pull-database-using-wcf-sql.html) that seemed to get me what I need.
However I keep getting a casting error when the Receive Location runs. I dont have any GUID's in my SP. I have even simplified my SP to a SQL statement returning hard coded strings.

**SELECT [Description] , PackageName FROM ( SELECT 'ABC' [Description] ,'123' as PackageName ) as ResponseTable**

the Schema expects two fields of type string.

See error below.

```
The receive location "Receive - Package" with URL "mssql://xxx/xxx?InboundId=PackageErrors" is shutting down. Details:"Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels.Common.AdapterException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Guid' to type 'System.IConvertible'.. Endpoint Address - mssql://xxx/xxx?InboundId=PackageErrors ---> <b>System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Guid' to type 'System.IConvertible'.</b>
at Microsoft.Adapters.Sql.SqlAdapterInboundHandler.Polling_WaitForMessage(TimeoutHelper timeoutHelper)
at Microsoft.Adapters.Sql.SqlAdapterInboundHandler.WaitForMessage(TimeSpan timeout)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.Adapters.Sql.SqlAdapterInboundHandler.WaitForMessage(TimeSpan timeout)
at Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels.Common.Channels.AdapterInputChannel.WaitForMessage(TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ErrorHandlingReceiver.WaitForMessage()".
```

Comment: Did you import the Binding File generated by the Wizard or create the Receive Location manually?

Comment: Yes I imported this Binding file manually.

Comment: Found the issue to be my polling statement missing the COUNT() part. And so it was actually returning the GUID mentioned in the error.

Answer (score 0):

That walk through is wrong in one aspect.

Rather than using the "Add Adapter Metadata" you would be better of using the "Consume Adapter Service", select the sqlBinding, Configure the URI, Connect, select Service (Inbound operations) for the contract type and select your stored procedure from there.

This will have the added benefits creating a binding file for your receive location, which you can then import and will be correctly configured.  It doesn't create an Orchestration like the Add Adapter Metadata, but I actually prefer that.