# BizTalk: Routing Failure Error when polling SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, biztalk, polling

I'm trying to poll a SQL Server for a simple SELECT stored procedure (the query itself executes perfectly well within SSMS), then email the results (with some transformation and message assignment) to a hardcoded recipient.

Within BizTalk, I have a Receive Port (using WCF-SQL configured to point to the target server using TypedPolling, and a PollingStatement of "EXEC dbo.[spRTest]"
This then feeds into the orchestration utilising a schema to map the response from the polled SP against a canonical schema, which then uses message assignment to define some SMTP details before firing an email out.

When it executes, I'm getting the common BizTalk error:

```
This service instance exists to help debug routing failures for instance "{23AC9101-13FB-4290-A2AC-CED7FEAB4064}". The context of the message associated with this instance contains all the promoted properties at the time of the routing failure.
```

I was initially getting errors relating to subscribers, but I've told the Send port filter to look at the Polled Receive Port, so the message should be getting received.

Just as a final note, I'm relatively new to the whole BizTalk concept, so it's very much a learn and burn process.

Thanks in advance

Comment: And is your Send Port a one way or a two way?   You need to look at the context properties of the Routing Failure to see 1) Where it came from 2) What properties it has that you expect to route on, and if they match the filters of where you expect it to go.

Comment: Seems WCF RL is configured 2 way

Comment: Looked further, & don't think its an issue with the send port. Recreated with clean, simple setup:

1 Receive port (Receive Location with TypedPolling to my server calling the test SP)
1 Send port (Flat file XML output, so it should just dump the results from the SQL into XML)
No transformations.
Can now see it seems to be some sort of connection error with the Receive location:

The adapter "WCF-SQL" raised an error message. Details "Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels.Common.AdapterException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Guid' to type 'System.IConvertible'..

Comment: Suspect I was completely doing this wrong from scratch, I've now followed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/adapters-and-accelerators/adapter-sql/receive-strongly-typed-polling-based-data-changed-messages-from-sql-in-biztalk to the letter (more or less), but at least I'm getting the above error still, so there's 'some' level of consistency with my issue

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22938224/unable-to-cast-object-of-type-system-guid-to-type-system-iconvertible

Comment: Thanks @Dijkgraaf - I've followed the way you've suggested in your reply, I suspect it's my interpretation of the Binding tab properties on both the schema generation AND the receive location ports.
If I have a simple SELECT * FROM STAFF WHERE staff_id = 'hardcodedvalue' as a stored procedure (spRTest), can I put EXEC dbo.spRTest in both the PolledDataAvailableStatement and PollingStatement fields? What would the overall diff between these 2 fields be?
Thanks

Comment: Thanks all - managed to resolve this, I'd not correctly entered the fully realised db names in my SELECT queries. Thatll teach me. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

It means you received a message from the polling port, but it couldn't route it to a send port or orchestration. Double check if your send port or orchestration is enabled and that you set the right filter property and value. For setting the right filter value, open the routing failure instance and look at the context properties available. You can use one of the context properties as filter property.

Comment: It sounds like that was his initial problem, but now he has something else.  Without more information we would just be guessing.